# How to get the relationship/formula between a result and a set of values?

Tags: python, r, regression

As the question states I would like to be able to get a formula based on the relationship between potential values (from a set of values) and a result.

Example:

Result: 13

Set of values: 3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 7, 9, 1

I would like to find what equation of the values would give the result (ie. 3 * 4 + 2 - 1), keeping in mind some of the values may be irrelevant in the final equation. The equation would not have to 100% accurate, finding something about 95-98% accurate would be fit for my purpose.

I assume this is a task that regression would be used for however I'm not sure where to begin. Ideally I would like to achieve this in Python or R and I'm guessing there would be some sort of packages that could be leveraged. I have many sets of values and results to run through to hopefully improve the accuracy of the model/equation, I'm not sure how many would be required to get a statistically significant accuracy.

Comment: What operators and functions are allowed in the equation? Your question reminds me of this problem: [Data-driven Discovery of Governing Physical Laws](https://sinews.siam.org/Details-Page/data-driven-discovery-of-governing-physical-laws). It's feasible.

Comment: I think I would just be looking at the basic operators - division, multiplication, addition and subtraction.